# AngularJs 1.5.8: how to check if the token is valid before sending every $http (get/post) request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and wondering how to check the `token`'s expire date and time before sending any request.

I googled and found there are concepts like `interceptors` and `decorators` in angular but I am a bit confused which one to use and how. Or is there any better way to do it.

**What am I doing right now?**

I have created a service that has `GET, POST` functions take url, data and config as parameters and there I am checking the token. I know this is not the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interceptor that will configure every $http call. [enter link description here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

Comment: I have also thought of it but `interceptors` gives you `request success/error` and `response success/error`. I need to check the token before sending the request

Comment: Why? You can try to use a refresh token system.

Answer (score 0):

You can write interceptor which will cancel invalid token request before it is actually sent:

```
return {
      'request': function(config) {
        if (condition) {
          var canceler = $q.defer();
          config.timeout = canceler.promise;
          canceler.resolve();
        }
        return config;
      }
}
```

Obviously, you can manipulate config before returning it and (for example) change token.